# ROS Navigation: Remove objects from the costmap with delay

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

at the beginning some information regarding my robot system:

```
Turtlebot 3 Waffle
Odroid XU4
360° Laser scanner (RPLidar A3)
IntelRealsense D435
```

Task IntelRealsense: detection of obstacles that are not detected by the laser scanner.

Both sensors have the authorization to enter and remove obstacles in the costmap.

Is it possible that objects detected by the IntelRealsense camera and entered in the costmap remain in the costmap for a certain time (delay), even if the object is no longer within the camera's field of view?

For local path planning I use the dwa_local_planner.

Edit:
The data of the IntelRealsense camera is converted into LaserScan Message by the package "depthimage_to_laserscan".

Best regards,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342396/ros-navigation:-remove-objects-from-the-costmap-with-delay/) by [BoC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33539/boc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-23**:
Would this be something [spatio_temporal_voxel_layer](http://wiki.ros.org/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer) could do?

@stevemacenski?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-23**:
That could work, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting the parameter "observation_persistence" (file: costmap_common_params.yaml) has solved my problem.

Thanks for your help.

---

Originally posted by [BoC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33539/boc/) with karma: 48 on 2020-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0